# Java Generics Nested Type Paramaters

Tags: java, generics

I have a class defined like so:
`public class AddRecordsToolbar<D extends IDataSource<T>, T extends Serializable>
       extends AbstractToolbar<D, T>`

which my IDE `IntelliJ IDEA` declares as legal.  It looks and *feels* wrong to me.
I *want*  to declare it like this:
`public class AddRecordsToolbar<D extends IDataSource<T extends Serializable>, T>
       extends AbstractToolbar<D, T>`
however that syntax is illegal thanks to something to do with Javas type erasure.

`D extends IDataSource<T>` is required by the superclass.
My Class is using Serializable to do a deep copy. Hence the T extends Serializable.

So now on to the Question:  If I specify `T extends Serializable` as the second type parameter for my class will it still enforce `T extends Serializable` for `D` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to your question, yes its do.

The order of generic parameter it only in your mind.

If we would rephrase that implementation to:

```
public class AddRecordsToolbar<T extends Serializable, D extends IDataSource<T>> extends AbstractToolbar<D, T>
```

you will be not so surprised, and looks that the way it should be.

I will try to find the explanation for this in Java Language Specification (when it will work) but for now that the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is addressed in section 8.1.2 of the java language spec:

> The scope of a class' type parameter is the entire declaration of the
>   class including the type parameter section itself. Therefore, type
>   parameters can appear as parts of their own bounds, or as bounds of
>   other type parameters declared in the same section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The "T" in the second parameter is the *same* T as in the first.  Nothing world work, otherwise.

This means that

```
class IFoo extends IDataSource<String>{};
AddRecordsToolbar<IFoo, Integer> x;
```

Is illegal. Integer and String are both serialisable, but the declaration of AddRecordsToolbar says that the data source has to be a source of the data type in your second parameter. And that second parameter says that it has to be serializable.